# Perlin noise looks too griddy

Tags: python, graphics, noise, perlin-noise

I've written my own perlin library and have also used one of the standard python libs for generating noise. This is the code I have bellow:

```
import sys
from noise import pnoise2, snoise2

perlin = np.empty((sizeOfImage,sizeOfImage),dtype=np.float32)
freq = 1024
for y in range(256):
    for x in range(256):
        perlin[y][x] = int(pnoise2(x / freq, y / freq, 4) * 32.0 + 128.0)
max = np.amax(perlin)
min = np.amin(perlin)
max += abs(min)
perlin += abs(min)
perlin /= max
perlin *= 255
img = Image.fromarray(perlin, 'L')
img.save('my.png')
dp(filename='my.png')
```

The image it generates is:[image]

Regardless of the frequency or octaves, it always looks gritty. It is my conclusion that I am thus using it wrong, but I'm not sure why my solution is wrong. I use fractional units via frequency and iterate through my 2d array. I've tried switching indicies and what not, but still there doesn't seem to be an continuity. How can I get smooth perlin noise?

Comment: Is this Python2.x? If so `x / freq` uses integer division and will round down to zero for all values in your loop

Comment: This is python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there were a few potential issues

- don't convert to `int` before normalising the range unless you want to lose precision
- to normalise, subtract `min` from `max` and `perlin` instead of adding `abs(min)`

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import sys
from noise import pnoise2, snoise2

sizeOfImage = 256

perlin = np.empty((sizeOfImage,sizeOfImage),dtype=np.float32)
freq = 1024
for y in range(256):
    for x in range(256):
        perlin[y][x] = pnoise2(x / freq, y / freq, 4) # don't need to scale or shift here as the code below undoes that anyway
max = np.amax(perlin)
min = np.amin(perlin)
max -= min
perlin -= min
perlin /= max
perlin *= 255
img = Image.fromarray(perlin.astype('uint8'), 'L') # convert to int here instead
img.save('my.png')
```

[image]

Comment: I feel like convert min to abs was absolutely where I went wrong. Thanks for the help!